# Using JavaScript inside PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

Ok so I have a booking system that I am working on and I have events created in a table which gets populated by PHP if the admin adds new events. I would like to run a script if the user tries to book an event and then submit the form to php. I would like to do this because I want to know if the user has a voucher and wants to pay either by card or via paypal.

Here is the table screenshot, sorry only a link I need 10 rep points.

[image: http://thomasniven.com/table.jpg]

The PHP code that creates the tables:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("flexiflash", $con);
 echo "<thead>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>ID</th>";
 echo "<th>Venue</th>";
 echo "<th>Event</th>";
 echo "<th>Date</th>";
 echo "<th>Time</th>";
 echo "<th></th>";
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "</thead>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<form class='table-form'  action='book_event.php' method='post' onsubmit='return check()'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Event_ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Event_Venue'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Event_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Event_Date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Event_Time'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' class='sub_btn' name='submit' value='Book now'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</tbody>";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**IF YOU NEED ANY MORE INFO LET ME KNOW**

Comment: I guess I should let you know that the voucher is a checkbox and the pay by card/pay via paypal are radio buttons

Comment: "I would like to..." Go ahead, come back here with specific errors when you get stuck.

Comment: SO isn't a tutorial site; you can't state your aim and expect people to give you the answer. As Chris says, we'll help you get over specific hurdles in **your solution**, but we won't **give you** the solution. What have you tried already?

Comment: So basically: "Dear people of Stackoverflow, build my thing"

Comment: To include Javascript into PHP you do exactly the same as you would have with HTML: echo "Your Javascript here"; What exactly is your question?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I think you can create javascript function and on Book Now button you will have to call that function to check  whether its paypal selected or Card ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is backend. JavaScript is frontend. What do you want to do in the frontend? Perform the check() function? If so, just put this

```
<?php

echo '<script>
function check() {
  //do something
  return true;
}
</script>';

?>
```

before the table. This should do it. But it's kinda ugly :)

Comment: I shall give this a try. Thanks. Maybe I didn't explain my question well enough. I am not asking for the answer to my problem but simply asking how I can go about running a script before submitting the form to my php. Thanks though.